# VBA WinHTTP to login into Oddsportal

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, winhttp

I am trying to login into oddsportal through a VBA script. I have written the following code but it is not working. I am getting an error when I am truing to set cookie for POST request. I would be thankful if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
Dim WHTTP As Object
Dim myuser, mypass, url, strAuthenticate As String
Dim out As String

url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/"

myuser = "user"
mypass = "pass"
strAuthenticate = "login-username=" & myuser & "&login-password=" & mypass & "&login-submit="

Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")

WHTTP.Open "POST", url, False
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
WHTTP.send strAuthenticate
strCookie = WHTTP.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")  **'I am getting an error here**
strResponse = WHTTP.ResponseText


WHTTP.Open "GET", "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/", False
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cookie", strCookie
WHTTP.send

out = WHTTP.ResponseText
```

I changed the authentication method to server based using setcredential method. Now I am able to set cookie from the first part. However, I am still unable to get the data from second page (second part of the code). Here are the response headers that I got using setcredentials: My set cookie line is only able to retain the last cookie.

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
   Connection: keep-alive
   Date: Tue, 27 May 2014 16:01:29 GMT
   Pragma: no-cache
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Content-Type: text/html
   Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
   Age: 0
   Server: Apache
   Set-Cookie: op_lang=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/
   Set-Cookie: op_oddsportal=fehof62734n35crjd9vpshhf10; path=/
   Set-Cookie: op_cookie-test=ok; expires=Wed, 27-May-2015 16:01:28 GMT; path=/
   Set-Cookie: op_state=1
   Set-Cookie: op_last_id=1; expires=Thu, 26-Jun-2014 16:01:28 GMT; path=/
   Set-Cookie: op_cookie-test=ok; expires=Wed, 27-May-2015 16:01:28 GMT; path=/
   Vary: Accept-Encoding
   X-Deliver: Tue, 27 May 2014 16:01:29 GMT
```

This is cookie that I get from Fiddler:

```
Set-Cookie:op_user_logout=0; expires=Mon, 18-May-2015 18:44:49 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:op_last_id=1; expires=Thu, 26-Jun-2014 18:44:49 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:op_user_login_id=95774; expires=Mon, 18-May-2015 18:44:49 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:op_user_login_hash=73a967ad18d6a353afa12877309f4708; expires=Mon, 18-May-2015 18:44:49 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:op_cookie-test=ok; expires=Wed, 27-May-2015 18:44:48 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:op_user_time_zone=1.00; expires=Thu, 26-Jun-2014 18:44:49 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:op_user_full_time_zone=35; expires=Thu, 26-Jun-2014 18:44:49 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:op_lang=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/
```

Comment: Do you have anymore details about the error you're getting?

Comment: Check `WHTTP.Status` after the send but before trying to get the cookie value

Comment: @barrowc: I check the status before getting the cookie value, it is 200

Comment: @Kyle: In the cookie line highlighted above, I get the error "Requested Header was not found"

Comment: Use `Debug.Print WHTTP.GetAllResponseHeaders` to find out which headers are actually being returned

Comment: @barrowc Cache-Control: public
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 27 May 2014 15:25:48 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Tue, 27 May 2014 15:26:17 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 27 May 2014 15:25:17 GMT
Age: 32
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Deliver: Tue, 27 May 2014 15:25:48 GMT

Comment: @barrowc: Please check my original questions I have made few findings.

Comment: I believe that the `WinHTTPrequest` object might handle all of the cookies for you so try commenting out the `strCookie = ...` line plus the line where you set the cookie request header then see what happens

Comment: @barrowc: it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will help in this specific case, but request and response cookies handling is included in my library [Excel-REST](https://github.com/timhall/Excel-REST). Here's an example of getting and setting the login id and hash:

```
Dim OddsClient As New RestClient
OddsClient.BaseUrl = "http://www.oddsportal.com/"

Dim LoginRequest As New RestRequest
LoginRequest.Method = httpPOST
LoginRequest.Format = formurlencoded
LoginRequest.AddParameter "login-username", myuser
LoginRequest.AddParameter "login-password", mypass
LoginRequest.AddParameter "login-submit", ""

Dim LoginResponse As RestResponse
Set LoginResponse = OddsClient.Execute(LoginRequest)

If LoginResponse.StatusCode = 200 Then
  Dim OddsRequest As New RestRequest
  OddsRequest.Resource = "soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/"
  OddsRequest.AddCookie "op_user_login_id", LoginResponse.Cookies("op_user_login_id")
  OddsRequest.AddCookie "op_user_login_hash", LoginResponse.Cookies("op_user_login_hash")

  Dim OddsResponse As RestResponse
  Set OddsResponse = OddsClient.Execute(OddsRequest)
End If
```

I had some difficulty retrieving cookies from headers, since every cookie has the same header key, "Set-Cookie". In Excel-REST I split `getAllResponseHeaders` into a `Collection` of key-value headers for ease of access and then pulled out those with the "Set-Cookie" key (See [RestHelpers](https://github.com/timhall/Excel-REST/blob/674fe34c980f9f2ef64f65bd9e3dd74f3b21da7a/src/RestHelpers.bas#L873)).  For your example, something similar to the following may work:

```
Dim Headers As Collection ' of Dictionaries with key, value
Set Headers = ExtractHeadersFromResponseHeaders(WHTTP.getAllResponseHeaders) ' from RestHelpers

' Setup GET...

Dim Header As Dictionary
For Each Header In Headers
    ' Move all cookies from login to GET request
    If Header("key") = "Set-Cookie" Then
        WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cookie", Header("value")
    End If  
Next Header
```